# Numpy random.choice only working in small loop, but not in bigger ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a While loop running to perform a monte carlo simulation. During the loop it calls a function that uses random.choice

```
def simulate_game(team1,rating1,team2,rating2):
    if team2 is 'bye':
        return team1
    else :
        matchup_arr = [team1,team2]
        pteam1 = 1/(1+10**((rating2-rating1)/250))
        pteam2 = 1- pteam1
        prob_arr = [pteam1,pteam2]
        winner = np.random.choice(matchup_arr,size=1,p=prob_arr)
    return winner
```

This works just fine if the while loop runs 1000 times or less. However, if I try to run it any more than that I get an error telling me that

**'p' must be 1-dimensional**

Any thoughts as to why random.choice would have an issue with this?...but only when it is being run more than 1000 times in a row

Comment: Specify the exact inputs that fail

Comment: So did you examine `prob_arr`?

Comment: prob_arr is the one that is failing, because that is the p input. But with every run it is just an array containing 2 values that total to 1.     [.7,.3]. or [.8,.2]

Comment: You believe it should be an array containing two values, but unfortunately, the error is definitive evidence that your belief is incorrect. And we can't tell you what exactly is incorrect with the information you've given us so far. So -- what function inputs cause the error? Do you know how to use try/except to print information when there's an error?